# Am I removed or not?

Tags: support, personal-question

there is something written in the opening window below my login name in Islam.SE that says: "-30  User was removed", what does that mean, am I removed in the sense Ahmadi has been banned or else? I just tried it by sending an answer to a question and the answer was sent to the forum so I am a little bit confused! Is it a mistake, a warning, a punishment, or really I am going to be removed? Clarification is appreciated :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means a user deleted their account. All their rep that they gave or took goes into a black hole.

In your case, this user (whoever it was) gave you +30 rep (eg. three up-votes to your answers). Since they're gone, the system reversed that rep.